# Is one hour long enough to transfer between ferries on Paros?

Tags: transit, ferries, greece

I booked a Sea Jets ferry from Mykonos to Paros, arriving at 10:30. I need to take the Blue Star ferry from Paros to Santorini, which leaves at 11:45.

Is the one hour plus long enough for this? I need to check in at the port and also collect the onward tickets.

Comment: Does the ferry arrive at Paros at 10:30 or at Mykonos?

Answer (score 5):

You should be ok but with a little risk because arrival times are not always accurate due to delays at ports before Mykonos. Sometimes delays happen but I think one hour and 15 minutes is quite enough. I believe you should be fine as long as nothing extreme happens. You can always call the PORT AUTHORITIES of your destination on the day of your trip in order for them to tell you the estimated arrival time of the specific ship at Paros. You can call them even after the ship has left from the starting port to Mykonos and they can update you. The port authorities of Paros telephone number is  +30 2284021240